# Node e2e tests - async beforeEach/afterEach hooks fail on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, async-await, mocha.js

On OSX and Linux, the following works great (this is as simplified a reproduction as possible, hopefully without sacrificing meaning):

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { MongoClient, Db } from 'mongodb';
import { Application, Request } from 'express';
import { Server } from 'http';
import * as config from 'config';

describe('some test', () =>
{
    let Session:{ new(app:Application):Request } = require('supertest-session'),
        app:Application,
        server:Server,
        mongoClient:MongoClient,
        db:Db;

    beforeEach(async () =>
    {
        app = express();
        server = app.listen(config.Http.port);
        request = new Session(app);

        // On Windows tests are executed before this resolves
        mongoClient = await MongoClient.connect(config.Database.connectionOptions.url);

        db = mongoClient.db(config.Database.connectionOptions.database);
    });

    afterEach(async () =>
    {
        await db.dropDatabase();
        request.destroy();
        server.close();
    });

    it('works like it oughtta', () =>
    {
        request.post('/api/account/login')
            .send({ email: 'me@example.com', password: 'password' })
            .expect(200)
            .then((res) =>
            {
                expect(res.success).to.eq(true);
            })
    })
});
```

On a Windows machine, the above fails with the following output from npm:

```
13 verbose stack Exit status 4
13 verbose stack       at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Path\To\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v9.4.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\index.js:285:16)
... rest of stack
13 verbose stack       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
```

If I take the database connection out of the `beforeEach` hook and do this instead, the test will run and pass, but I still notice hard-to-track-down failures in further tests with async hooks:

```
before(function(done)
{
    MongoClient.connect(function(err, client)
    {
        mongoClient = client;
        done();
    });
});

after(function(done)
{
    mongoClient.close(function() { done(); });
});
```

I've seen this behavior using Mocha, Jest and FuseBox test runners. Running node@9.4 on both machines. The solution to this *cannot* be "just make sure I test my tests on a Windows machine before I push".

Comment: `const app = express();
        app.listen(config.Http.port);
        request = new Session(app);` Shouldn't these line be outside the `beforeEach` ?

Comment: @AbhinavD, I could give that a shot later and see if it helps. I'm also destroying the session and app in the afterEach block. Forgot to put that in my example. I'll edit it.

Comment: Sure. The scope of variables defined in the `beforeEach` block will not get to the `it` block of the test.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't everything in the top-level describe block be in that scope? And if not, why would that be different across operating systems?